# Error Less2CSS plugin while compiling less file in Sublime Text 2

Tags: less, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I installed `Sublime Text 2` and `Node.js`.After that i install `less` with that command `npm install -g less` with command console.When i install `Less2CSS` plugin and try to compile less file then i am getting error 
  `The compress option has been deprecated. We recommend you use a dedicated css minifier, for instance see less-plugin-clean-css`
.I found the same issue on [here also](https://github.com/timdouglas/sublime-less2css/pull/106).But i didn't understand what and which file to change.please help me if anyone have same issue.I attached the screen shot for more understand the issue.Thank you everyone.[image]

Comment: The changes you need are pretty evident [there](https://github.com/timdouglas/sublime-less2css/pull/106/files). Nothing more to add beside that PR.

Comment: which file and where ?

Comment: It's clearly written the page linked above (the file name, the line, what to replace/remove exactly). There's no reason to copy-paste this info there.

Comment: i did but facing same issue .i changed line number 184 but still same .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this issue, go to Sublime Text and:

1. Go to Preferences > Browse Packages
2. Open the Less2css folder
3. Open the lesscompiler.py file in a text editor
4. Go to line 184 and change this

   cmd = [lessc_command, less, css, "**-x**", "--verbose"]
5. to this

   cmd = [lessc_command, less, css, "**--clean-css**", "--verbose"]
6. Save the file, restart Sublime Text, and attempt to save your LESS file again.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the option is not supported. it recommend you use a dedicated css minifier.

You can change the option.

Via `"Preferences" -> "Package Settings" -> "Less2Css" -> "Settings - Default"`.

change `["minify": true,]` to `["minify": false,]`

and then, if you want to minify the css file, please use a dedicated css minifier to do this.